# How to access Athena from lambda function

Tags: python, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, serverless, amazon-athena

I am using serverless for deploying lambda function on aws. My lambda function triggered when object is created in particular bucket and insert records in Athena. when lambda function is deployed and lambda is triggered then it give me following error:

> botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the StartQueryExecution operation: User: arn:aws:sts::[SERVICE]:assumed-role/[PROJECT]-dev-us-east-1-lambdaRole/[SERVICE]-dev-collector is not authorized to perform: athena:StartQueryExecution on resource: arn:aws:athena:us-east-1:[MY_ACCOUNT_NO]:workgroup/primary.

My serveless.yml is

```
service: MY_SERVICE

plugins:
  - serverless-python-requirements
custom:
  bucket: MY_BUCKET
  pythonRequirements:
      pythonBin: python3

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python3.7
  stage: dev
  region: us-east-1
  iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: "Allow"
      Action:
        - "s3:*"
      Resource:
        - arn:aws:s3:::${self:custom.bucket}
        - arn:aws:s3:::${self:custom.bucket}/*

    - Effect: "Allow"
      Action:
        - "athena:*"
      Resource:
        - arn:aws:s3:::${self:custom.bucket}
        - arn:aws:s3:::${self:custom.bucket}/*

functions:
  collector:
    handler: collector.run
    events:
      - s3:
          bucket: ${self:custom.bucket}
          event: s3:ObjectCreated:*
          rules:
            - prefix: test_folder/
          existing: true
```

Any Idea how can i grant permissions to lambda function so it can insert records in athena?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just added the these items in serverless.yml file i.e. give access to athena and glue under `iamRoleStatements` tag and it works for me.

```
iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: "Allow"
      Action:
        - "s3:*"
      Resource:
        - arn:aws:s3:::${self:custom.bucket}
        - arn:aws:s3:::${self:custom.bucket}/*

    - Effect: "Allow"
      Action:
        - "glue:*"
      Resource:
        - "*"

    - Effect: "Allow"
      Action:
        - "athena:*"
      Resource:
        - "*"
```

Answer (score 0):

Lambda execution role should allow access to Athena. and your S3 bucket.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": [
        "athena:StartQueryExecution"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
      "Action": [
        "s3:*"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::your-bucket-name/*"
    } 
  ]
}
```

Comment: How to define these setting in serverless.xml file ?

Comment: in the second allow statement in your template, your allow "athena:*" action on s3 bucket but should reference your athena service

Comment: how can i reference my athena service in serveless.xml file ?

Comment: You can find here alot of examples: https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/iam/

Comment: Can't find any example related to athena.